# Conversion by cast when indirect route exists

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, casting

Can someone explain the rules of casting, and when a conversion is ambiguous? I'm getting slightly confused by the following case, which *gives different answers* on MSVC++ (Visual Studio 2010) and gcc-4.3.4.

```
#include <string>

class myStr
{
  std::string value;

public:
  myStr(const char* val) : value(val) {}
  operator const char*() const {return value.c_str();}
  operator const std::string() const {return value;}
};

myStr byVal();
myStr& byRef();
const myStr& byConstRef();

int main(int, char**)
{
  myStr foo("hello");
  std::string test;

  // All below conversions fail "ambiguous overload for 'operator='" in gcc
  // Only the indicated coversions fail for MSVC++
  test = foo;  // MSVC++ error "'operator =' is ambiguous"
  test = static_cast<std::string>(foo);

  test = byVal();  // MSVC++ error "'operator =' is ambiguous"
  test = static_cast<std::string>(byVal());  // MSVC++ error 
             // "'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'myStr' to 'std::string'"

  test = byRef();  // MSVC++ error "'operator =' is ambiguous"
  test = static_cast<std::string>(byRef());

  test = byConstRef();  // MSVC++ error "'operator =' is ambiguous"
  test = static_cast<std::string>(byConstRef());

  return 0;
}
```

What rules govern which of those conversions is legal? And is there any compliant way to use unambiguously a class like `myStr` which defines casts to both `const char*` and `const std::string`?

Comment: `std::string` can be constructed with another `std::string` or with a `const char *` so when you're trying to use the `static_cast`, wich of the ctors do you like to be invoked? that's the ambiguity.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster - Fair enough. Do you know how MSVC++ can resolve three of the `static_cast`s, but not the other one?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster - actually, no, thinking about it I'd expect `static_cast<std::string>` to invoke `operator const std::string`, leaving an unambiguous assignment. Why should the compiler try `operator const char*` followed by construction when I've told it to cast to `std::string`?

Comment: I am not sure the compiler is a smart as you think.  When it looks at the code it finds that your call could be done by either of the two operators, it might be obvious to a human you which you mean but a compiler will just throw an error and let you sort it out.

Comment: @Stefan - But the line reads (to my mind) "cast myStr to std::string; assign result to std::string". Isn't it clearly better to invoke `operator std::string` for the first, instead of `std::string(operator const char*())`? In any case, _how_ can I "sort it out" and get the compiler to use the right one?

Comment: @Chowlett, yep it reads that to my mind too.  However, all a compiler is going to see is two possible operators which might apply and no way of telling which one you meant.  Do you need to return a std::string one at all if the char* one can already perform the task?

Comment: @Stefan, yes; I have functions which take `const char *` and which take `std::string`, where I have a `myStr` in hand. Without the `std::string` cast the latter can't be called without an intermediate because you can't perform more than one conversion when parameter passing.

Comment: In order to call the assign operator `test = static_cast<std::string>(Foo());` a temporary `std::string` must be created in the proccess. So the compiler looks at the object `myStr` (wich is the return type of `byVal` and `byRef`) and tries to convert this object into a `std::string` and realizes that have two ways to do it, first one through `std::string operator` and the other one through `const char * operator`; so the ambiguity is served. In order to get rid of it, I (personally) will delete the `const char * operator` just because a string can get transformed into `const char *`.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster - Not directly; you need to call `.c_str()` (and that conversion is the older one in `myStr`, so I'd rather not remove it). Why isn't `operator std::string` preferred when converting to a `std::string`? It's a shorter conversion chain.

Comment: @Chowlett `const char *` isn't a shorter conversion chain than `std::string`, the way it takes to convert is the same:

`Foo()` -> `myStr` -> one or other operator -> `std::string`

The moment the compiler arrives to `myStr` object it must decide wich way may take to construct a `std::string` choosing between the pointer one or the object one because both of them are possibles due the ctors of `std::string`, but the steps you must do become a string are the same.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster - I buy that for `test = foo;`, but in `test = static_cast<std::string>(foo);` am I not saying "cast `myStr` to `std::string` (which has only one shortest possibility), then assign that to `std::string`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implicit conversions are all ambiguous, since `std::string` has overloaded assignment operators taking both `const std::string&` and `const char*`. This means that both of your conversion operators are equally good choices, hence the ambiguity:

```
myStr -> std::string -> operator=(const std::string&)
myStr -> const char* -> operator=(const char*)
```

The ambiguities with `static_cast` are because you're using the cast to create a temporary `std::string` object. It's equally valid to create that from either a `std::string` or a `const char*`, so again both of your conversion operators are considered.

```
myStr -> std::string -> static_cast<std::string>(std::string)
myStr -> const char* -> static_cast<std::string>(const char*)
```

You can break the ambiguity by instead casting to a reference:

```
test = static_cast<const std::string&>(foo);
```

This will still create a temporary, since the conversion operator returns an object. However, that conversion is now implicit, and so can't involve more than one user-defined conversion; therefore, it can only be done via your `operator std::string()` and there is no ambiguity.

```
myStr -> std::string -> static_cast<const std::string&>(std::string)
myStr -> const char* -> std::string -> static_cast<const std::string&>(std::string)
      ^^             ^^  two implicit user-defined conversions - not allowed
```

You might also consider changing the conversion operator to return a `const` reference, so that the unnecessary temporary can be avoided.

Comment: Ah, that makes some kind of sense. Any thoughts on why MSVC++ lets me get away with three of the `static_cast` cases?

Comment: @Chowlett: That compiler has "extensions" which will accept all kinds of broken code; I'm not surprised that it tries to guess at what an ambiguous conversion should do.